# About installing kali-linux default terminal emulator on other linux distro

Tags: terminal, kali-linux, emulators

The terminal emulator used in kali-linux is very convenient to use.
How to check current terminal emulator name.
How to install this emulator in ubuntu/debaian other linux distro.

Answer (score 0):

Some terminal emulators have menus which will tell you what they are; for example, the current default terminal emulator in Kali Linux is [QTerminal](https://github.com/lxqt/qterminal), and its Help menu has an About… entry which will give you its name and version.

More generally, you can run

```
pstree -s $$
```

from a shell; this will show you the shell and its parents. The terminal emulator will in most cases be the shell’s immediate parent.

QTerminal is available in many distributions; in Debian derivatives, run

```
sudo apt install qterminal
```

to install it.

Comment: It's working...
Thank you.